# Why split string is done in many questions in hackerrank?

Tags: c++

It is Chief Hopper Greedy algorithm question .Here it is

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/chief-hopper/problem

I  want to ask why splitting of  string is done even though we are not giving any string as input and after that they used stoi function to convert that in int ??

```
string arr_temp_temp;
getline(cin, arr_temp_temp); 
vector<string> arr_temp = split_string(arr_temp_temp);
vector<int> arr(n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int arr_item = stoi(arr_temp[i]);

    arr[i] = arr_item;
}


vector<string> split_string(string input_string) {
string::iterator new_end = unique(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), [] (const char &x, const char &y) {
    return x == y and x == ' ';
});

input_string.erase(new_end, input_string.end());

while (input_string[input_string.length() - 1] == ' ') {
    input_string.pop_back();
}

vector<string> splits;
char delimiter = ' ';

size_t i = 0;
size_t pos = input_string.find(delimiter);

while (pos != string::npos) {
    splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, pos - i));

    i = pos + 1;
    pos = input_string.find(delimiter, i);
}

splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, min(pos, input_string.length()) - i + 1));

return splits;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where did u find this approach but from my point of view author trying to save time on IO operations. I think that this approach is wrong. I don't know how fast is reading string with getline compared to reading each int value one by one in the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) cin>> x;
```

But I'm quite sure that converting string to integer is more time-consuming. So it's normal in competive programming to use scanf/printf for the fast IO or

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(nullptr); cout.tie(nullptr);
```

if you wanna use cout/cin.
To sum up I think that code author tried to save time on IO operations.

**UPD**: Sorry I was in rush and didn't take into account the platform. It should be this platform feature to read input only line by line so they give a template for you to focus only on the problem.